# How to open markdown preview by default to the bottom?

Tags: visual-studio-code

By default, the markdown preview in VS Code opens on the Side. I do this action quite a bit and I always have to drag a drop it to the bottom of the current tab.

[image: Markdown Preview button and title]

I looked in my settings to see if there was a way to change this default behavior and didn't see anything that looks like it would change it.

[image: Settings]

Any suggestions on how to change this default setting?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use one of the extensions that allow to execute multiple commands and do:

1. `markdown.showPreviewToSide`
2. `workbench.action.toggleEditorGroupLayout`